# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException could not be parsed migrating from Java 8 to Java 11

Tags: java

This works in Java 8

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("4/11/17 00:00 AM", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/yy hh:mm[ ][a]"));
```

But in Java 11 I get

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '4/11/17 00:00 AM' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 14
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2049)
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
```

Can anyone help me understand why this is? I've checked the docs and don't see any obvious change to the DateTimeFormatter class.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: Index 14 is the `A` in `AM`, maybe an optional am-pm-of-day is not allowed anymore when you are using hours in 12-hour format (`hh`), but that's just a guess. Does it work without the braces around the `a`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nothing changed. You're committing a 'default platform' code style error. This is an anti-pattern where you use a broken method and break your code, but the bug is almost impossible to find with unit tests; your code will end up blowing up at production time when lots of cash and reputation is on the line. "Fortunately", you found this bug today by switching JDKs and getting lucky that the locale configurations are somehow different between your JDK installations.

I suggest you grow just as much of a dislike to these bad methods as I do :) These  methods are ones that presume some parameter to be 'whatever your platform has as a default for this value', and the 3 common culprits are, in order:

- Charset encoding
- Locale
- Timezone

`ofPattern(String)` is one such method; it presumes 'the platform default locale', and evidently, on your JDK8 install, it's english or something similar and on your JDK11 install it is not. Parsing `AM` as value for an `a` field is locale dependent; obviously, AM is an englishism, it wouldn't make any sense in dutch or french!

There are 2 things to do to fix this problem:

1. If your IDE has features to mark a method as 'you really should never call this', you should strongly consider adding all of these methods to the list, and if you then want platform default, that you explicitly use things like `Charset.defaultCharset()` instead, to make clear you really want that.
2. Fix your code by shoving a `, Locale.ENGLISH` after your pattern and all will be right as rain again.

An example:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("4/11/17 00:00 AM",
  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/yy hh:mm[ ][a]",
  Locale.forLanguageTag("NL")));
```

will fail on JDK8 just as much as it does on JDK11.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("4/11/17 00:00 AM",
  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/yy hh:mm[ ][a]",
  Locale.ENGLISH));
```

works on JDK8 and JDK11 too.

NB: A bunch of non-english locales such as `.GERMANY` and `.ITALY` and `.FRANCE` actually do somehow parse AM correctly, but as shown above, dutch (The Netherlands) is an example where that won't work.

Comment: I really like this explanation. For `GERMANY`, I can say it's totally uncommon to use the 12-hour format anywhere in any way (apart from analogue clocks/watches). Since this *englishism* is actually an abbreviation of the Latin terms *ante meridiem* (pre noon) and *post meridiem* (after noon) it got adopted to German (if used at all). Would appear ugly to abbreviate the German equivalent *Vormittag* and *Nachmittag* by *VM* and *NM*, anyway.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this was the problem. Fortunately this was caught in a unit test.

Comment: @deHaar good point - that explains why this works in german, english, italian, and french, but not in e.g. dutch. Here in NL it's just as rare to use as 12-hour clock, but if you do, technically we do have `v.m.` and `n.m.` (voormiddag, namiddag), which are bizarre shorthands (it's one word, so why a dot after the v/n anyway?), but presumably that's what the `a` pattern is trying to match against in locale.dutch. It's an 'englishism' in the sense that 12 hour clock is common usage there but not in most of mainland europe.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Dat is interessant (that's interesting). I didn't know there's a local abbreviation for this anywhere in the world. Sure, you're right about the *englishism*, 12-hour format is common if not default in nearly all English speaking cultures, I think.

Comment: In IntelliJ, go to File  > Settings > Editor  > Inspections > Java > Internationalization.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu. Apparently Java picks up locale from the OS, which for me is en.GB. In my unit test I print out the locale (System.out.println(Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage());) which returns English. And yet I still require the locale to be set to English on DateTimeFormatter for this code to work. Clearly this should be set anyway but thought this was interesting.

Comment: @F_SO_K now _that_ sounds like a bug. Unless en.GB somehow doesn't parse AM and PM.